# PHP Find and replace a part of string with regex

Tags: php, regex

I want to find and replace a part of string start and end with.
Example:

```
<LAT>43.654209136963</LATS>
<LONGS>-0.59365832805634</LONGS>
<LAT>44.362339019775</LATE>
```

Become:

```
<LATS>43.654209136963</LATS>
<LONGS>-0.59365832805634</LONGS>
<LATE>44.362339019775</LATE>

-Line1: <LAT> => <LATS>
-Line3: <LAT> => <LATE>
```

Thanks for your helo

Comment: If you had to solve this yourself, where would you start?

Comment: Please keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a code writing service. See [here some hints on how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the ending tag is always the correct one, based on that, we simply replace the opening tag with the closing tag, i.e.:

```
$xml = <<< LOB
<LAT>43.654209136963</LATS>
<LONGS>-0.59365832805634</LONGS>
<LAT>44.362339019775</LATE>
LOB;

$xml = preg_replace('%<(.*?)>(.*?)</(.*?)>%m', '<$3>$2</$3>', $xml);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/LhUd0R)

Comment: Thank you very much, Pedro Lobito.
It worked like charm.
Thank you very very very much again.

Comment: You're very welcome @CuongNguyen